# How to make delay microsecond in AVR (ATmega8) with timer?

Tags: timer, delay, avr, avr-gcc

I want to make variable delay in ATmega8. But in function delay_us(), I can just put a constant value. I think I can make a variable delay microsecond with a timer but I don't know how to work with this.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you share what you already done?

Comment: when I write delay_us(i) and i is a variable,codevision errored.

Comment: Please provide some code. You can´t set a variable to `delay_us` because `delay_us(x)` is a macro which insert some additional code which generates a delay of `x` µ-seconds. When you need a variable delay you have to use a timer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a delay loop: you delay for one microsecond in each
iteration, and do as many iterations as microseconds you have to burn:

```cpp
void delay_us(unsigned long us)
{
    while (us--) _delay_us(1);
}
```

There are, however, a few issues with this approach:

- it takes time to manage the iterations (decrement the counter, compare
  to zero, conditional branch...), so the delay within the loop should
  be significantly shorter that 1 µs
- it takes time to call the function and return from it, and this should
  be discounted from the iteration count, but since this time may not be
  a full number of microseconds, you will have to add a small delay in
  order to get to the next full microsecond
- if the compiler inlines the function, everything will be off.

Trying to fix those issues yields something like this:

```cpp
// Only valid with a 16 MHz clock.
void __attribute__((noinline)) delay_us(unsigned long us)
{
    if (us < 2) return;
    us -= 2;
    _delay_us(0.4375);
    while (us--) _delay_us(0.3125);
}
```

For a more complete version that can handle various clock frequencies,
see [the `delayMicroseconds()` function](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.2/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L120) from the Arduino AVR
core. Notice that the function is only accurate for a few discrete
frequencies. Notice also that the delay loop is done in inline assembly,
in order to be independent of compiler optimizations.